# c# Entity Framework Remove an added object from the Data Context before SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to remove entities from the Context before SaveChanges is called.

the entities are added like so

```
DbContext.Set<T>().Add(new T());
```

Originally I would remove single items by setting their state to EntityState.UnChanged where applicable in my overridden DbContext.SaveChanges() method.

But where I have multiple entities that I do not want persisted, when the second entity has its state changed to UnChanged I get an error - "Saving or accepting changes failed because more than one entity has the same primary key value" - obviously they all have an ID of 0 because they haven't been saved yet.

When I try

```
DbContext.Set<T>().Remove(entity);
```

it just doesn't remove the entity

I know setting the EntityState to UnChanged was a bit of a hack I discovered years back, and now its come back to bite me!

If any body can tell me how to remove an unsaved entity from the DbContext before saving I will be most grateful.

Best Regards

Lance

Comment: I think it is better if you set entity state to Detached.

Comment: You can take a look at ChangeTracker within your context of save changes, but it eludes the fact that you are missing the <Key> attribute on your POCO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try detaching it, this way EF will stop tracking it and will not take any actions to serialize changes against DB.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.core.objects.objectcontext.detach(v=vs.113).aspx

```
((IObjectContextAdapter)DbContext).Detach(entity);
```

Comment: Thank you Hazimdikenli. I also worked out my framework wasn't clearing down temporary working copies of the entity which compounded the error as initially your solution appeared to not work.

Comment: any help for ef core